# Nginx + Gunicorn - error pages for static resources

Tags: python, http, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am running a Python Flask application with Gunicorn and Nginx as a reverse proxy. Pages are served by Gunicorn and Nginx is serving files from my static folder directly.

It's working correctly except where I get a 404 on a static resources.

I have setup custom error handlers in Flask to show 'pretty' error pages on HTTP error codes. This is also working fine when I request a non-existent page.
However, when a static resource doesn't exist then nginx serves its own default 404 page instead of the Flask app's 404 page (which makes sense since it's bypassing Gunicorn). Is there a way to tell nginx to serve the Flask error handler page via Gunicorn if it encounters an error serving a static resource?

Here is my current nginx conf file for this server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/logs/error.log;

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

    location /static {
            alias /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/app/static/;
    }
```

}

I'm thinking (hoping) I can use an error_page directive to give control back to Gunicorn and tell it to serve the appropriate custom error handler, but haven't been able to figure out if that's possible or how to do it from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I was able to locate an answer to this after alot of searching so posting it here for the benefit of anyone else who may have the same issue. I expect this would work for any backend, not just gunicorn.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

In the section entitled 'Trying Several Options' the final example shows the solution to this problem, using the try_files directive in the static location block I can tell nginx to pass the request to a named location if it fails to find the requested file.

Here is my new nginx conf file which is working as expected now for non-existent static file requests:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/logs/error.log;

    location @apwd_flask {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @apwd_flask;
    }

    location /static {
            alias /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/app/static/;
            try_files $uri @apwd_flask;
    }

}
```

Now my location @apwd_flask is the gunicorn backend and when my static files aren't found by nginx serving directly, it sends the request to the backend which serves its own 404 response.

Comment: The configuration fits your purpose but for the performance it is bad. First nginx will fail looking for the file and than forward the request to gunicorn. It will fail another time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the owner of files in below directory

```
/home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/app/static/
```

In order to give access to nginx user to read files in the static directory change the owner to www-data or change the owner group to www-data and give the read access to all files in this directory.

You can do this by running below command:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/aaron/dev/apwd-flask/app/static/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you have misunderstood my question. There is no issue with the file permissions,  I have asked how to serve my error pages via Gunicorn when the static file truly doesn't exist. I since found the answer to this and have posted it as an answer to this question.